What is this phenomenon where a narrow stream of airflow off a nacelle becomes visible?
I few hours ago I was on an A321neo going across states. As we were approaching and descending to the runway, I saw this cool effect near the engine and wing fixture:

If you look near the engine, you will see airflow. But why is it condensed near that spot specifically? Why not anywhere else? What is the physics and aerodynamics between such a phenomenon?

Related (including more cool pictures): What is this flange on the engine?

It's basically an artificially generated tornado laying on its side. As with an upright tornado, you see it because of condensation of water vapour due to the pressure drop in the core.

Just wanted to add that I saw this recently as well, thought it was pretty neat!  My pictures and a quick video: https://imgur.com/a/cGHAk17

It's the visible vortex created by the fan cowl strake at the engine of the A320
Below is an image of the same on a Boeing 737,

On jet aircraft where the engines are mounted in nacelles slung under the wings, strakes may be added to one or both sides of each nacelle to produce vortices that energize the airflow over the wings in times of high angle of attack, such as during takeoff and landing, thus improving wing effectiveness.
Sometimes due to humidity and other atmospheric conditions the vortex generated by these is visible prominently.
Some more info about these from R.S. Shevell. Aerodynamic Bugs: Can CFD spray them away? 1985

DC-10 wind tunnel tests showed a significant loss in maximum lift coefficient in the flap deflected configurations, with landing slat extension, compared to predictions. This resulted in a stall speed increase of about 5 knots in the approach configuration. The initial wing stall occured behind the nacelles and forward of the inboard ailerons. The problem was traced by flow visualization techniques to the effects of the nacelle wake at high angles of attack and the absence of the slat in the vicinity of the nacelle pylons. The solution was developed in the NASA Ames Research Center 12 ft. pressurized tunnel and turned out to be a pair of strakes mounted forward on each side of the nacelles in planes about 45 degrees above the horizontal. The final strake shape was optimized in flight tests. The strakes are simply large vortex generators. The vortices mix the nacelle boundary layer air with the free stream and reduce the momentum loss in the wake. The vortices then pass just over the upper surface of the wing, continuing this mixing process. The counterrotating vortices also create a downwash over the wing region unprotected by the slat, further reducing the premature stall. The effect of the strakes is to reduce the required takeoff and landing field lengths by about 6%, a very large effect.

Related:

What is this flange on the engine?
In what conditions are visible Wingtip vortices created?
Can these vortices be dangerous?

